# Issue linking gcc-4.7 Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, gcc, g++

So I downloaded gcc using homebrew so that I could update gcc and g++ to 4.7.

So then I:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
```

created `~/.bashrc` with contents:

```
'export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH'
```

created `~/.bash_profile` with contents:

```
'. $HOME/.bashrc'
```

and then:

$ `ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++-4.7 ~/bin/g++`

so now I run `g++ -v and it's 4.7`, YAY!

Now I go to update gcc and do:

$ `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.7 ~/bin/gcc`

I get no errors but then when I run gcc -v i get:

```
gcc-4.7: error trying to exec '/usr/local/bin/i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

So it seems to be looking for 4.2 for some reason? If I cd to `~/bin/gcc` and do `./gcc -v` it works fine. Also echo $PATH has the correct `~/bin path`. I'm not sure why g++ worked and gcc didnt.

Comment: First, what does "which gcc" return? Second, are you really sure you want to do this? Hiding your other compilers in this way is probably a bad idea (for one thing, homebrew won't like it), as is running gcc through a symlink instead of out of its native directory.

Comment: Wait a second: "If I cd to ~/bin/gcc and do ./gcc -v it works". If that's accurate, this means you have a directory called ~/bin/gcc, and the symlink is ~/bin/gcc/gcc, which of course isn't in your path.

Comment: which gcc returns: /Users/user/bin/gcc.
I'm not sure that I want to hide the compilers this way haha, I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.
And sorry, I cd to ~/bin, and then do ./gcc -v.

Comment: What is the "this" you actually want to do? You can already run gcc-4.7 out of /usr/local/bin, because that's in your path. So, what's the point of the symlinks? Are you trying to trick everything into using gcc-4.7 (which will break most packages, and Homebrew itself), or are you just trying to save yourself a few keystrokes?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to all of this. I didn't realize I could just have my Makefile use g++-4.7. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Yes, your makefile can use g++-4.7, or you can even override the default in any given build by setting CC and CXX in the environment or passing them to make, without trying to trick your toolchain… Meanwhile, if you're still interested in why gcc -v works in some cases but not others, I'm at a loss, maybe someone else has some ideas.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
This is because bash has hashed the gcc in other folder.

```
run: hash gcc
```

Then everything should go smooth.